# how to recover my code (algorithms etc) after grub broken

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery

grub is broken in my computer. I have tried many ways to repair it but failed, probably because the grub is installed in /usr/sbin, not in /dev. I now want to save my code (my algorithms etc) before I try some ways else such as re-install ubuntu 18.04. However, my user folder cannot be found. The only folder at /home is ubuntu but that is not mine.

My questions are: How can I recover my work? Will my work be lost after a re-installation of ubuntu? Thank you!

Comment: You can boot from a live drive (Ubuntu in a USB drive), mount the partition(s) in the internal drive, find your code (algorithms etc) and copy it to another drive, a backup drive. - After that you can try to repair the grub bootloader with [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If that does not help, re-install Ubuntu. - Finally restore your code from the backup drive to where you want it in the installed system.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I successfully found my code and backed-up.

Comment: As you've discovered, the Live Linux variations make things like this easy. At the same time, it's not always effective. As such, it's in your best interests to have a good backup process. The 3 - 2 - 1 backup [plan](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/data-backup-plan-how-to-implement-the-3-2-1-backup-strategy/) is generally considered the best practice and industry standard. Also, if you haven't tested your backup then you have no backup.